# Remove Blank Rows from a Multi Line Text Box and populate the array with the textbox elements

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I am totally new C# coding. Actually I need to know that how can I remove the blank rows from a multiline textbox and then populate the array with its elements?
Suppose my textbox will have the data as:

```
d1
d2

d3



d8
```

so I want to ignore the blank line after d2 and so after d3 then populate my array with the data so that the array should have only:

```
 array={d1,d2,d3,d8} and not the blank lines data?
```

can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var array = txtBox.Text.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

That will split the TextBox's Text into array by new line character. And automatically remove empty elements by specifying split option to RemoveEmptyEntries.

Comment: Thanks and I'm new to c# so nice of you sir!